# Python kill bash while loop started from subprocess

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, exec

I am trying to execute the bash script `while :; do afplay beep.wav ; done` command from a python script, but be able to kill it afterwards.

I tried:

```
process = subprocess.Popen("exec while :; do afplay %s ; done" % fileName, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13143013/3310334) suggests, but the above doesn't work for me. (The script doesn't run.)

How can I run `while :; do afplay beep.wav ; done` from python and kill it at any point after it is started?

---

**EDIT**: just noticed that `exec >(while :; do afplay %s; done)` will launch the script, but now `process.kill()` won't kill it.

Comment: Type `help exec` instead of `man exec`, since `exec` is a builtin. Then you'll see that `exec` executes _commands._ If you think about it a little bit, it doesn't make sense to `exec` non-external commands `;)`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I am trying to execute the `while :; do afplay beep.wav ; done` command from a python script, but be able to kill it afterwards. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13143013/3310334) shows an easy way to kill a bash script from python, and I tried to copy it but it didn't work.

Comment: Then make all this clear in your question! You need to heavily edit your question!!!

Comment: OP, be serious, `exec >(...)` is not what you want at all, it's not even semantically correct.

Comment: I tried it with the accepted answer in the question you linked, and it works well, without `exec` and other horrible hack. What's your OS?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf macOS. without exec, the while loop is killed but the process inside it continues until it's finished

Answer (score 1):

```
os.killpg(os.getpgid(process.pid), signal.SIGINT)
```

this seemed to do the trick. I am killing the process group (`os.killpg`) instead of the sole process.